# how to make len work within VBA across range?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
For Each cell In Sheet7.Range("C:C")
    If Len(cell.Value) <> 6 Then
        MsgBox " has the wrong length"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
```

This doesn't seem to work :(

It should detect if even one cell in given range does not equal 6 digits, generate message box and exit sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `len()`, you are testing the length of a string in a single cell.  If you want to see if all the cells in a range have a certain length, you would need a loop.

**EDIT#1:**

For example:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If Len(cell.Value) <> 6 Then
            MsgBox cell.Address & " has the wrong length"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: ```for each c in sheet1.range("$D:$D")
if len(c.value) <> 6 then
```

doesn't seem to be working either :(

Comment: @plshelpimpoor please update your question to show the new code you tried.

Comment: @plshelpimpoor See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent check my original post, can't seem to add line break in comment. your code did work by the way. But I am looking to keep it simple where it just generates the error. the reason being because I have it under another sub, so in the event even a single error is generated, the sub will exit.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work by getting sub to end before it goes to next cell. A question though

```For Each cell In Intersect(Sheet1.Range("C:C"), Sheet1.UsedRange)```

Am I doing this right? Not sure what UsedRange means.

Comment: @plshelpimpoor  You are doing very well......`UsedRange` limits the looping so the code does not test the millions of un-filled cells at the bottom of column **C**